# Bootstrap with grid responsiveness works only with a 15-character first word

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get responsiveness with simple Bootstrap. Responsiveness works only when I use the first word with more than 15 characters as shown below.

[image]

```
<!-- Headers -->
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col">
   <p>1234567</p> <!---- not responsive-->
   <p>123456789012345 there is difference between knowing 
     the path and walking the path</p> <!-- responsiveness -->
</div>
<div class="col">
    <form> ...</form>
</div>
```

How to get responsiveness without having change length of the first word of the a sentence.

[image]

Comment: you may use col-sm, col-md etc.. based on the screensize to achive the output you want

Comment: In bootstrap there is called `Grid system` where you set the width of each element base on the target screen sizes.
[Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand how the bootstrap grid system works. So I think the following link will help you to study the bootstrap.
If you want to study the bootstrap 3 then refer the following link of Bootstrap 3 grid system will help you.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

If you want to study the bootstrap 4 then refer the following link of Bootstrap 4 grid system will help you.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Also, you need to learn media queries, that will help you to design a responsive layout. Refer the following link for understanding media queries and breakpoints.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

According to your layout in the image, the following code will help you. Run the code snippet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 text-center">
   <p>1234567</p> <!---- not responsive-->
   <p>123456789012345 there is difference between knowing 
     the path and walking the path</p> <!-- responsiveness -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 reg_form">
    <form class="text-center">  
  <h4> Registration </h4>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
  <input type="checkbox"> I agree. <br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
 </form>
</div>
```